# Plain monomorphism,the defintion

Tags: functions, category-theory, monomorphisms

In several places the notions of a **plain monomorphism** or a plain **epimorphism** are used, but never defined.
See eg. [here](https://books.google.cz/books?isbn=0521834147) on page 60,
or search google with query

> plain monomorphisms tholen

Do they mean a general mono, as opposed to extremal or strong or regular?

Comment: What means "tholen"?

Comment: It's the name of the author of the book reference.

Comment: It would be better to quote the context, rather than give a quest hook the reader might follow to try and find it.

Comment: [See here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/epimorphism) and search for the word "plain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, "plain" just means there are no additional assumptions, as opposed to things like extremal.  So "plain monomorphism" means the same thing as "monomorphism".